# What does this capacitor do?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, rf, analog, radio

[image: Schematic]

Preface: I am not an EE and just a hobbyist. I designed this FM radio circuit and it works as shown.

My Question:
When C4 was originally, 1nF, there was no output on C2. Once I experimentally picked a value of 30pF, there was 3V on the the output cap C2.

Why does the value of C4 matter? Is the job of C4 more than isolating DC?

My only guess is 30pF a better impedance match between the transistor stages. What is going on there?

Edit: [image: C2 measurment]
Waveform measured on C2 is 3V peak to peak, and the antenna going into TR1 gives a 20-40mV peak to peak signal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Why does the value of C4 matter? Is the job of C4 more than isolating
> DC?*

[image]

There's a chance that C4 will act with L1 (170 nH) to form a tank circuit at TR1's collector. You say that when C4 equals 30 pF that your FM slope detecting receiver works fine so, if you did the math on a tank circuit formed by 30 pF and 170 nH, you'd get a resonant frequency of 70.5 MHz.

That's just a ball-park calculation just to see what the resonant frequency is with C4 being 30 pF.

However, it will be higher than that; the miller capacitance of TR2 will, in effect be in series with C4 and that value for the 2N3904 is about 4 pF but, TR2 is fairly high gain and inverting so, it will amplify the effect of the 4 pF by possibly ten-fold thus, the true resonance around the collector of TR1 might be due to C4 in series with maybe 40 pF. That comes out at 93.2 MHz and pretty much in the middle of the FM broadcast band.

If C4 were 1 nF then the effective capacitance would be 1 nF in series with 40 pF and, that equals 65.4 pF. That would tune with L1 to 47.7 MHz and be way-off the middle of the FM broadcast band.

Of course, the better way to check this is through simulation and I'm encouraging you to do so.

<sub>Also note that the 2N3904 is a poor choice here because it has unity current gain at 270 MHz and this means that at 100 MHz, the current gain might only be single figure numbers. In different words; there are a lot of loose-ends that make really accurate performance observations difficult hence, why I suggest you use a simulator.</sub>

Comment: Fantastic analysis! My understanding of the miller effect is that as frequency increases, the value of the miller capacitor between collector and base increases. Interesting to think about a series LC filter being formed between L1, C4, and the miller capacitor of TR2. I also attached a waveform measured on C2, input to TR1 is in the range of 20mV, output of entire amp stage is like 3V. Not sure what is going on with the current gain.

Comment: @YousifAlniemi glad to be of some help. I think if I were in your shoes I'd bee plotting TR2's collector AC voltage vs the input signal across a range of frequencies just to see if things look about right for the middle of the FM band. The miller capacitance remains fixed with frequency but, its impedance will lower with increasing frequency.